# Audio Output Device Array is of length 0 on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mediadevices, audio-device, amazon-chime

I am working on a video conferencing app that leverages Amazon Chime. I have followed the npm page of [Amazon Chime SDK JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-chime-sdk-js) and managed to get the server response and initialized the meetingSession. However, the problem is when I try to get an array of audio output devices, it is an array of length zero on Safari whereas in browsers like Chrome and Firefox, it works just fine, and I get an array of non zero length. How do I solve this?

Here is what I have coded so far:

```
import {
  ConsoleLogger,
  DefaultDeviceController,
  DefaultMeetingSession,
  LogLevel,
  MeetingSessionConfiguration
} from 'amazon-chime-sdk-js';
 
const logger = new ConsoleLogger('MyLogger', LogLevel.INFO);
const deviceController = new DefaultDeviceController(logger);
 
// You need responses from server-side Chime API. See below for details.
const meetingResponse = /* Server response */;
const attendeeResponse = /* Server response */;
const configuration = new MeetingSessionConfiguration(meetingResponse, attendeeResponse);

const meetingSession = new DefaultMeetingSession(
  configuration,
  logger,
  deviceController
);

const audioInputDevices = await meetingSession.audioVideo.listAudioInputDevices();
const audioOutputDevices = await meetingSession.audioVideo.listAudioOutputDevices();
const videoInputDevices = await meetingSession.audioVideo.listVideoInputDevices();

/* Rest of the code... */
```

When I log the lengths of the above arrays in the console, the length of `audioOutputDevices` array is zero
in Safari whereas it is non zero in other browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output/speaker device selection is not enabled by default in Firefox and Safari. So you have to change the default settings:

The below steps are tested on macOS Catalina (v: 10.15.7)

a) **Firefox:**  This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/12471

1. In the url bar type *about:config*
2. Search in the searchbar for the property *media.setsinkid.enabled* and set it to true
3. Relaunch the browser and test (open the following link in the browser https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/). You should now see values in the drop down of Audio Output Destination

b) **Safari (Tested on version: 14.1.2):**

1. Make sure you see the Develop tab in the top right (if not then enable it "*Safari > Preferences > Advanced*" and then check "Show Develop menu in menu bar" at the bottom)
2. Navigate to "*Develop > Experimental Features > Allow Speaker Device Selection*" and make sure "*Allow Speaker Device Selection*" is checked
3. Relaunch the browser and test here https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

If you want to inform the user then you can have something like below(pseudo code):

```
ioDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
let outputDeviceSelectable = false;
for (let device: ioDevices) {
    if (device.kind == "audiooutput") {
        outputDeviceSelectable = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (outputDeviceSelectable == false) {
    show a pop up to the user to change the default settings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue according to the [Amazon Chime SDK FAQ](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/blob/master/guides/06_FAQs.md#i-am-unable-to-select-audio-output-device-in-some-browsers-is-this-a-known-issue): **Firefox and Safari have known issues disallowing them from listing audio output devices on these browsers. While clients can continue the meeting using the default device, they will not be able to select devices in meetings.**